# How can I replace all hotmail.com addresses in a file with another email address, using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have multiple email id's in some config files in a directory; I'm running my scripts on a Solaris machine. I want to perform the following:

Find all the email_id's in the config files in a directory:
eg: abcd@hotmail.com ; dfgh@hotmail.com ; mnop@hotmail.com ; fghk@hotmail.com

Replace all existing id's with:
wxyz@hotmail.com

The following implementation can help me replace "hotmail" with "gmail" for all the email id's in the config files. But i'm a little confused to solve the above problem

```
perl -pi -e 's/\@hotmail/\@gmail/g' *
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to make backups of your files as you go? `perl -pi.bak blahblahblah` See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*[_extension_] for more info.

Comment: The link should be:  `perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*[_extension_]` SO eats it if I put the http on the front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
's/\S+@hotmail\.com/wxyz@hotmail.com/g'
```

Comment: Pleased it worked. Regex is very powerful if you use it right

Comment: It can also be very powerful if you use it wrong. You should escape the dot so that it doesn't just match any old character.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an editor with regex/global replace (and make sure it creates *.bak files)

sure, coding this is fun ..

Comment: But the correct regular expression to achieve this would still be needed.

Comment: I didn't claim it wasn't .. I was pointing out, that writing a program might not be the ideal solution, unless the problem arises often.

Answer (score 0):

using the solution posted by heferav, i don't seem to get the answer

```
$ more file
abcd@hotmail.com ; dfgh@hotmail.com ; mnop@hotmail.com ; fghk@hotmail.com
$ perl -ne 'print if s/\S+@hotmail\.com/wxyz@hotmail.com/g' file
wxyz.com ; wxyz.com ; wxyz.com ; wxyz.com
```

maybe I am missing something.
@OP, since you are working in Solaris, i assume you can use nawk

```
$ nawk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/.*@hotmail.com/,"wxyz@hotmail",$i)} }1' file
wxyz@hotmail ; wxyz@hotmail ; wxyz@hotmail ; wxyz@hotmail
```